# Laravel executing GET instead of POST request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, laravel-5.4

I have form to POST data to Controller and update database

The form in my `orders.blade.php`

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <select name="selectdb" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Delivery Boy</option>
        @foreach($delvery_boys as $delvery_boy)
          <option name="selectdb" data-oid="{{$order->id}}" value="{{$delvery_boy->id}}">{{$delvery_boy->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="assigndb-btn btn-floating waves-effect waves-light">
        <i class="material-icons">send</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

I am doing an ajax POST request of form data to controller in my `orders.blade.php`

```
$(document).one("click", ".assigndb-btn", function () {

    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var order_id = $(this).find(":selected").data('oid');
        var delivery_boy_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var delivery_boy_name = $(this).find(":selected").text();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('/manager/assign_orders') }}',
            type: 'POST', 
            data: {"order_id":order_id,"delivery_boy_id":delivery_boy_id},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

And in my `OrdersController.php` i have the logic to updated the posted data

```
public function assignDeliveryBoy(Request $request)
{
    $assign_delivery_boy = Order::where('id', $request->order_id)->update(['delivery_boy_id' => $request->delivery_boy_id]);

    $data = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Order has been asigned'
    ];

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

My Route is

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth','roles'], 'roles' => 'manager'], function() {
    Route::post('/assign_orders', 'OrdersController@assignDeliveryBoy')->name('assignOrder');
});
```

When i submit the form it suppose to hit the `assign_order` route and update the database

But in my console i am getting the html code of the page from where i submit the form basically it is executing `GET` instead of `POST`

As i checked in browser network whent the response is

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/manager/orders //but i am posting to http://localhost:8000/manager/assign_orders
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

i really don't understand what is wrong

thank you

Comment: comment out this route and try to post the data once and check if it gets response,

Comment: i'm getting 
orders:838 Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Comment: that means the url you are passing is being faulty, just keep the url like this and check url: ''/manager/assign_orders",

Comment: isn't your route missing the "/manager" part before "/assign_orders" ?

Comment: @Amarnasan  i have shared live url in above comment could you please chek

Comment: You need to put the `action` to be assign orders, currently it will submit to self.

Comment: Man, that's not the way this page works

Comment: remove leading `/` . `/manager/assign_orders/` will be `get` request. Make sure your url is `/manager/assign_orders` not `/manager/assign_orders/`.

Comment: you need to keep the url to this in ajax '/assign_orders,

Comment: @Exprator i din't get you, did you check the url i shared you

Comment: yup, its getting a 302 to assign orders, follow the url : '/assign_orders' or url: '{{ route("assignOrder") }}'

Comment: @Exprator thanks for your time really appreciate it, did you possibly observe in network, as soon you submit it will hit the `manager/assign` order and then it redirects to `manager/orders`

Comment: yes as because the redirection occurs because the ajax was not getting the url properly

Comment: @Exprator so what is the solution now

Comment: i am posting a ans, try to use it in the ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('/manager/assign_orders') }}",
    type: 'POST', 
    data:{
         "order_id":order_id,
         "delivery_boy_id":delivery_boy_id,
         '_token':'{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: i have updated the code in live, i'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: xhTh41gTzGilo6R8xbJdOjIF7OgZaN9JVTRbopxa is not defined
    at Object.doneFunction (orders:836)
    at l (sweetalert.min.js:1)
    at Object.s [as handleButton] (sweetalert.min.js:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.g (sweetalert.min.js:1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('assignOrder') }}',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {"order_id":order_id,"delivery_boy_id":delivery_boy_id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you i really appreciate your time, i have tried this but the result is same, i you could please do check the live url i shared in above comments

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("assignOrder") }}',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {"order_id":order_id,"delivery_boy_id":delivery_boy_id,'_token':'{{ csrf_token() }}'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: indeed as you can see, now i have updated my code, but the result is same

Comment: can you remove the form from the blade? as you are using ajax there is no need of that,

Comment: this is really a wired response, i even tried without `ajax` when i sumit the form the page just refreshes without any changes

Comment: ya i'll try that

Comment: It just refreshes because you don't have any action= attribute in your form.

Comment: @MrRobot now i can see you have got it working, right? now the ajax is getting 200 and datas are getting saved

Comment: ya i had to post ` '_token':'{{ csrf_token() }}'` as well @Adarsh Sojitra helped me with this, and thank you for your time i really really appreciate it